# How to display data from backend?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I learn use axios and I want to display all name of clients. I use Laravel 9 and Vue 3. This is my code in List.vue component. My problem is that this code display nothing. Someone could me help where i do mistake ? Royer is sure correctly, and in my backend controler this is my code.

```js
 public function index()
    {
        $customers = $this->service->getList();
        $response = [
            'data' => $customers
        ];
        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

```js
<template>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ clients.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "List",
    data() {
        return {
            clients: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get('/clients')
            .then(response => (
                this.clients = response.data.clients
            ))
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: do a console.log(response) or console.log(response.data) and see what you get, from what i see you may have to do: this.clients = response.data.data.clients

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `clients` is currently an array, you should loop through the array and display the name of each client as bellow.

```
<template>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr for"client in clients" :key="client.id">
            <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>
```